# Configure xmobar to show workspaces

Tags: xmonad, haskell

What should my xmonad.hs file look like to correctly give workspace info to xmobar?

Comment: The [XMonad wiki has the details](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html)...

Comment: I would still welcome an answer to this question -- the wiki contains snippets, but not a full config, so unless you already know your way around Xmonad, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution to add Xmobar is this configuration:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog

main = xmonad =<< xmobar def
```

But usually, Xmonad users prefer to adapt their desktops. This is a more popular way to add Xmobar:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Util.Run

main = do
    -- start Xmobar process
    h <- spawnPipe "xmobar -d"
    xmonad $ def {
            -- this adds a fixup for docks
            layoutHook = avoidStruts $ layoutHook def,

            -- this adds Xmobar to Xmonad
            logHook = dynamicLogWithPP $
                    xmobarPP {
                            ppOutput = hPutStrLn h
                            },

            -- this adds a second fixup for docks
            manageHook = manageDocks <+> manageHook def
            }
```

Xmobar does not look nice like this, in my opinion. In most cases, people add a custom Xmobar [configuration](http://projects.haskell.org/xmobar/#configuration) and override further [PP properties](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html#t:PP) that are preconfigured with `xmobarPP` here.